# USDT TRANSFER MADE INTO A USDC WALLET

Tags: metamask, coinbase, usdt, usdc

Can a transfer made into the wrong address wallet be reversed? I transferred funds from USDT to my USDC wallet. What can I do to get this funds back? PLEASE HELP ME.

Comment: Please post a link of the transaction in question. There is no such thing as a USDT or USDC wallet in ethereum. Only an ethereum wallet (for all tokens).

Comment: they are all ERC20 TOkens and work the same, so do you have the private key of your "USDC" wallet?